# Python Assert exception

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am having phyton code in 10 databricks cell in a single databricks notebook.

The first cell contains the below code.

```
df = spark.sql(f"""select * from test.table """)
count= df.count()
```

Here if count is 0 , I want the notebook to fail, if the count is greater than 1 , I want the rest of the cells in the databricks notebook to execute.

Im trying the below code.

```
 df = spark.sql(f"""select * from test.table """)
    count= df.count()
    assert count <= 0
```

The above code is not raising an assertion error, instead it just says query returns no results and executes the next cell in the databricks. Could someone please let me know to raise an assert exception and terminate the notebook without execution further cells.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your assertion backwards.  You assert what you need
to be true.

```
assert count > 0
```

(What's that `val` on the first line? Is that a cut-paste error?)

===

to answer the question below:

```
if count <= 0:
    raise AssertionError("must return at least one record")
```

You might look at the [list of built-in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) exceptions to see if one of those feels more appropriate than the generic "assertion error" for your circumstances.

Comment: Note that relying on this assert in final production code is bad practice: assert is for tests and developing.  It can be optimised out in production: raise a real exception if you need one

Comment: @2e0byo Could you please let me know to raise an exception in this case.

Comment: @SanjanaSanju `assert cond[, "message"]` is equivalent to `if not cond: raise AssertionError("message")`.  So just use `if` and some appropriate error (or a custom error): probably something like `ValueError` here